# Get a list of all gems bundled from source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is there a way to detect which gems in your environment have been loaded from source, via the path options?

ie:

```
# Gemfile
source 'rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'rails-extension', path: '~/code/rails-extension'
```

.

```
# some_script.rb
require 'rubygems'

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']) 

if defined?(Bundler) and not Bundler.sourced_gems.empty?
  puts "Using gems from source. Not safe to push to origin."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Path class from Bundler](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/source/path.rb), The following does the job:

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])


Gem.loaded_specs.values.map { |g| puts "#{g.name} from #{g.source}. Not safe to push to origin." if g.source.instance_of? Bundler::Source::Path }
```